# Python parking rate

Tags: python

```
def cal_parking_fee (parking_duration):
    if parking_duration< 60:
        fee = 2.5
    else:
        fee = 1.80 + 2.50
    return(fee)

hours = int(input("Enter minutes "))
total_fee = cal_parking_fee(hours)
print(total_fee)
```

Hi I'm trying to practice my python programming and I am stuck with this particular question. It says to Write/define a function called `cal_parking_fee` that takes in one parameter `parking_duration` in
minutes and return the fee payable based on the duration and parking rate. The rate is first hour of parking is $2.50 and every 30 min of parking thereafter is $1.80. I cant seems to make my code to work with the every 30 mins part.

Comment: If parking_duration is in minutes as per your request, why are you converting it from hours?

Comment: If minutes is more than 60, you are constantly returning 1.80 + 2.50. There is something wrong with that, that can you figure out what?

Comment: @Pitto oppsie my bad ! I'll remove the line

Comment: @Moberg I cant seem to understand how to add 1.50 for when the user enter lets say 180 mins

Comment: You need to be able to calculate how many times you have to add the 1.80. 

You add 1.80 every time the clock ticks 30 minutes. 

What about trying to do something like parking_duration_in_minutes / 30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def cal_parking_fee (parking_duration):
    duration_mins = parking_duration 
    # duration_mins = parking_duration * 60
    if duration_mins < 60:
        fee = 2.5

    else:
        duration = duration_mins - 60
        fee = 2.5
        while duration > 0:
            duration = duration - 30 
            fee = fee + 1.80
    return(fee)

hours = int(input("Enter hours "))
total_fee = cal_parking_fee(hours)
print(total_fee)
```

Comment: Hi i've tried this out , there's not a need to change the duration to hours as i am supposed to get input , minutes from the user. I cant seem to get the answer $4.30 when the user enters 70 mins .

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach

```
def cal_parking_fee (parking_duration):
    fee = 2.5
    if parking_duration > 60:
        # Here I subtract 2 because the 1st two 30 minutes
        # have a fixed fee of 2.5 that we've already set
        if (parking_duration / 30 - 2) == 0:
            periods_to_pay = 1
        else:
            periods_to_pay = (parking_duration / 30 - 2)
        fee += periods_to_pay * 1.8 
    return(fee)

hours = int(input("Enter minutes "))
total_fee = cal_parking_fee(hours)
print(total_fee)
```